# BitBucket Webhook gives Crumb issues while posting to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, postman, bitbucket, webhooks

I am trying to setup webhook from Bitbucket to Jenkins but it is failing while testing them crumb issues. This Jenkins is deployed to Kubernetes 1.17 and Jenkins is the latest image 2.249.1 . Even from PostMan I am getting the same issue. I know there is something wrong in Jenkins Setup only.

Error :

Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are triggering the job as a pre-push script, if its throwing crumb errors, you need to create personalized API token within Jenkins and would need that to be embedded in the API call from Bitbucket to Jenkins.

Please refer this article for generating a token - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003090592-How-to-re-generate-my-Jenkins-user-token

Comment: Hi , I am not getting crumb issues anymore but now from bitbucket the the request is reaching jenkins as I can see it in the Jenkins system logs but the pipeline job is not getting started.

Comment: HI @viswanathanand, if you still have the issue, can you see what is preventing the job to not start ? Were you able to trigger it manually from the UI ? Can you also see if the webhook is able to trigger it , that is from Bitbucket webhook logs do you see a 200 HTTP code ?